# In how many ways can I choose $x$ integers with a minimum difference of 2 between any of them?(Through recurrences)

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recursion

I would like to know if the following is a valid question. How can I choose $x$ integers from the first $n$ integers such that there is a minimum difference of 2 between any two chosen integers.

My method: Seeing the bijection between chosen integers and $n$-digit long binary sequences($1$ if integer is selected, $0$ if not), let $a_n$ be the number of ways required to choose digits from $n$ integers such that no two are consecutive[sorry if my language is unclear]. So, sequences can either start from $100...$ or $0...$.
Hence $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-3}$. But could you help me with the initial conditions? And, with further proceedings too. Thank you.

Comment: Your recurrence is correct for if you are given $n$ and you are summing over all possible $x$.  If you need the answer for a given $(x, n)$, your recurrence is not gonna work because it doesn't track $x$.  Instead the new recurrence would be $a(n,x) = a(n-1, x) + a(n-3,x-1)$.

Comment: @antkam  Sorry sir, I don't know working with recurrences having 2 different variables. Could you show me how, or direct me to a place where I can learn about them? Thanks!

Comment: are you required to solve this using recurrences?  because i think there is an easier way.

Comment: Not necessarily, but I wanted to see a recursive approach. It'll help me a lot. But please feel free to show the 'easier' way.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont need to use recurrences, this question has a simple closed form solution hinted at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3384468/how-many-ways-are-there-to-choose-k-numbers-from-first-n-natural-numbers-suc) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2119496/546005).

If you want to use recurrences, it is $a(n,x) = a(n-1, x) + a(n-3,x-1)$.  However, I don't know how to turn that into a closed form solution.  (I'm not good with generating functions.)  I suppose, since you can find the closed form (from the links above), you can then prove that it fits the recurrence, and thereby prove it inductively.  But that's a bit of cheating, right?  Because how would you know what the closed form solution looks like in the first place?